# Is it okay to edit a video with a dog in it and add a song to it?

Tags: work, music, dogs

Assalamu Alaikum.

I am a designer, sometimes I edit videos. I need to edit a video of a dog driving. I just need to add a logo, text and a song over the video.

My questions are, is it okay to add graphics on a video with a dog in it and add a song over it.

Answer (score -1):

sorry if I understood your question wrong since you don't have an islam tag.

yes it is okay, it's not haram to look at a dog; dog's are generally haram because they are considered dirty, it's haram to get one inside your house, but it's fine as long as it's outside of the house, you can even touch a dog, but you must clean your hands afterwards.